# Creating and adding events and tasks from Android Ginger bread supported phones

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am developing an Android application.
As a part of that, I need to have calendar inside that , where I can add events, tasks in that. I came across few answers stating that I need to add Google calendar for this purpose. I wish to have the events and tasks have to reside inside my application only. So, I need to use the phone's in-built calendar for this.

1. Is all the Android phones have in-built android calendar application?
2. If not, how can i create a calendar application within my application? Is there any Android
   library available for this purpose(which supports Even Ginger bread)

Comment: 1. No; 2. That's a HUGE question, but I'm pretty certain there is no "library" available for the entirety of it. You might be able to find a custom Widget that provides a calendar view.

Comment: @323go do you mean to say , i need to bundle an calendar widget along with my application for my purpose? if so , please suggest me a good widget and the way to bundle it as well.

Comment: I said "you might be able to find" a custom Widget. I didn't say "I'm going to spend an hour searching google for you."